# How to inject a third party script that has document.write after the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So basically this code is supposed to inject a script based on the user's location.

```
$.ajax("http://freegeoip.net/json/"+ip)

.done(function(data)

{
  if(data.country_name == "India")
  {

var geodata = '<script type="text/javascript">amzn_assoc_ad_type ="responsive_search_widget"; amzn_assoc_tracking_id ="murkind-21"; amzn_assoc_marketplace ="amazon"; amzn_assoc_region ="IN"; amzn_assoc_placement =""; amzn_assoc_search_type = "search_widget";amzn_assoc_width ="auto"; amzn_assoc_height ="auto"; amzn_assoc_default_search_category =""; amzn_assoc_default_search_key ="";amzn_assoc_theme ="light"; amzn_assoc_bg_color ="FFFFFF"; <\/script><script src="//z-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&Operation=GetScript&ID=OneJS&WS=1&Marketplace=IN"><\/script>';
$("#fdsa").html(geodata);
}


}

    );
```

The above code gives me the following errors:

> 1. "Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened."
> 2. GET https://ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=IN&Operation=GetAdHtml&OneJS=1&slotNum=2&height=auto&placement=adunit&theme=light&tracking_id=""&bg_color=FFFFFF&width=auto&ad_type=responsive_search_widget&marketplace=amazon&search_type=search_widget&region=IN&default_search_category=&default_search_key=""&viewerCountry=IN&jsonp=amzn_assoc_jsonp_callback_adunit_2 net::ERR_ABORTED

So after some googling I learned about something called postscribe and gave it a try.

```
postscribe('#fdsa', '<script type="text/javascript">amzn_assoc_ad_type ="responsive_search_widget"; amzn_assoc_tracking_id =""; amzn_assoc_marketplace ="amazon"; amzn_assoc_region ="IN"; amzn_assoc_placement =""; amzn_assoc_search_type = "search_widget";amzn_assoc_width ="auto"; amzn_assoc_height ="auto"; amzn_assoc_default_search_category =""; amzn_assoc_default_search_key ="";amzn_assoc_theme ="light"; amzn_assoc_bg_color ="FFFFFF"; <\/script><script src="//z-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&Operation=GetScript&ID=OneJS&WS=1&Marketplace=IN"><\/script>');
```

With postscribe, I dont get the document write error anymore but I still get the GET error.

Comment: Is the data that you're trying to get with Ajax served from the same domain as your site?